# How to throw user back to the coming URL after successful login in flask login?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am creating a flask login system. Where my URL "/profile" is restricted so whenever any user want to access the "`/profile"` URL they will be throw out to the login page.

But after successful login user are redirected to the URL.

I want that user should be thrown out to the `"/profile"` instead of redirected URL after successfully login.

Here is my login route -

```
@app.route("/login", methods = ["GET" , "POST"])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('pass')
        keep_log  = request.form.get('keep_log')
        if keep_log == "on":
            remember_me = True
        else:
            remember_me = False
        user_account = Register_data.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user_account:
            if check_password_hash(user_account.password,password):
                login_user(user_account,remember=remember_me)
                flash(f'WELCOME {user_account.name} ')
                return redirect(url_for('home'))
            else:
                flash(f'USERNAME OR PASSWORD IS INCORRECT')
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            flash('This email is not registered yet!. Create A New Account To Continue.')
    return render_template("2login.html")
```

I want to modify this URL to the user coming URL -

```
return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Kindly help me .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. You possibly want this:

The user(without login) get to the "`/profile`" page. For the user has not logged , he was redirected to "`/login`". After successful login, he was redirected to "/profile" page. Is that right?

So in your code:

```py
from flask import redirect, request
from flask_login import current_user

@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated():
        # ...
        return redirect(url_for("login", next_page="/profile")) # send an url arg to login page
    # ...

@app.route("/login")
def login():
    # ...
    login_user(user_account,remember=remember_me)
    flash(f'WELCOME {user_account.name} ')
    next_page = request.args.get("next_page") # get the url argument
    return redirect(next_page)
    #...
```

This is the explicit way, actually there is an implict way: you just need to define the `next` url argument and it will automatically redirect to that url.

Hope this will solve your problem.